# Subtracting two user input dates C++20 with std::chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm searching for a method to subtract two dates (ISO 8601 format) which are passed by the user as argument vector. Currently I have this pseudocode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char**argv){

    std::istringstream ssStart{argv[1]};
    std::istringstream ssEnd(argv[2]);

    std::chrono::year_month_day tStart, tEnd;
    ssStart >> std::chrono::parse("%Y-%m-%d", tStart);
    ssEnd >> std::chrono::parse("%Y-%m-%d", tEnd);

    auto tDays = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::days>(tEnd.day()-tStart.day());
    std::cout << ssStart.str() << "," << ssEnd.str() << "," << tDays.count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which works if you stay within the same month eg. `./main 2024-01-01 2024-01-31` -> `30`, but once you change months `./main 2024-01-01 2024-02-01` the result will be `0`. I could sum the diff between `year`, `month` and `day`, but I'm looking for a better solution (I'm skipping error checking for now since this is only a proof of concept).

I've read that `year_month_day` is not the right structure to use, so please assist me in choosing the correct one.

As stated in the title I use the C++20 standard (`g++-14`), and no external libraries.

Comment: Why are you isolating `day()` before computing the difference? That only gives a "day" in the range of 1 to 31, ignoring the month. Just don't do that, and it will work as expected.

Comment: please do not remove includes from the code before posting it. They are part of the [mcve], without the code does not compile and anybody who wants to see what the code does has to add them back

Comment: moreover, for testing you want a function taking two strings. This function you can then test with hardcoded input. Once you know it works you can pass command line arguments to the fucntion

Comment: Here is better demo: https://godbolt.org/z/KE3v8GeWj

Comment: @Ext3h, are you referring to `tEnd.day()-tStart.day()`? There is no `-` operand to subtract two `year_month_days` at once afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year_month_day` is an appropriate type to parse from a string input, but it doesn't support arithmetic. There is however a conversion to `std::chrono::sys_days`, which is a specialisation of `std::chrono::time_point`.

```
auto tDays = std::chrono::sys_days{ tEnd } - std::chrono::sys_days{ tStart };
```

`tDays` is a `std::chrono::days` value already.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed gives the right results no matter the month or year values (including negative values :) ).